# Proper usage of lua tables/classes

Tags: class, lua

I'm trying to use class behavior in lua where there is a ship that has two other classes pos and vector
But I cannot get it working like I assumed I would be able to

```
Point = {x=0, y=0}
function Point:new(p)
  p = p or {}
  return p
end

Ship =
{
  pos = {Point:new{x=0,y=0}},
  vector = {Point:new{x=0,y=0}} -- I thought this would be sufficient for access being available for vector
}

-- create new ship class
function Ship:new(pos)
  p = p or {}
  p.pos = pos
  p.vector = Point:new{x=0,y=0} -- I need to do this or accessing vector will crash (The problem)
  return p
end

-- Create new ship...
plrShip = Ship:new{}
plrShip.pos.x = 300
plrShip.pos.y = 300
```

If anyone knows how to make the above code cleaner/better I would be thankful

Answer (score 0):

You can use metatables to set default fields. (I've made some assumptions about what you're trying to do. If this doesn't work for you, please add some clarification to your question.)

```
local Point = {x=0, y=0}
Point.__index = Point
function Point:new(p)
  p = p or {}
  setmetatable(p, self)
  return p
end

-- create new ship class
local Ship = {}
Ship.__index = Ship
function Ship:new(pos)
  setmetatable(pos, Point)
  local p = {pos = pos, vector = Point:new()}
  setmetatable(p, self)
  return p
end

-- Create new ship...
local plrShip = Ship:new{}
plrShip.pos.x = 300
plrShip.pos.y = 300
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is what I wanted but is there no other way than using setmetatable and all the __index stuff?

Comment: Metatables are usually the best way to set default fields. The alternative is to copy the default tables into each new object, which you partially do in your answer. If you give us specifics on what you're trying to do, we might be able to find an easier way.

Comment: Just making a space ship that travels. It needs position and vector for this. And I wanted to create a generic Point class to hold these values. The code I created is pretty much my first attempt on lua classes

Answer (score -1):

I found solution to do this, it still not perfect but only I got working was this modified code:

```
Ship =
{
  pos = Point:new{x=0,y=0},
  vector = Point:new{x=0,y=0}
}

function Ship:new()
  p = p or {}
  p.pos = self.pos
  p.vector = self.vector
  return p
end

plrShip = Ship:new()
plrShip.pos.x = 300
plrShip.pos.y = 300
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? Every `Ship` will point to the same two `Point` objects. If you ever modify those `Point`s, it will effect every `Ship`.

Comment: Oh no, how do I fix that?

Comment: You could create both `Point`s in the `Ship:new` function.

Comment: Like: p.pos = Point:new {x=0,y=0}  ?   I cant get the default values of Point to work...

Comment: You could either use the same technique in `Point.new` (`return p or {x=0, y=0}`) or make `Point` into a metatable, as in my answer.